# Pandas groupby sum is not including columns of type timedelta when there are also columns of numeric type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Prepare dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Desc': ['abc', 'abc', 'abcd'], 'Duration': ['01:30:00', '02:00:00', '00:30:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'])
print(df)

#    Desc Duration
# 0   abc 01:30:00
# 1   abc 02:00:00
# 2  abcd 00:30:00
```

Groupby sum with one column works fine:

```
print(df.groupby('Desc').sum())

#      Duration
# Desc         
# abc  03:30:00
# abcd 00:30:00
```

Add a third column:

```
df['Duration (%)'] = df['Duration'] * 100 / df['Duration'].sum()
print(df)

#    Desc Duration  Duration (%)
# 0   abc 01:30:00          37.5
# 1   abc 02:00:00          50.0
# 2  abcd 00:30:00          12.5
```

Try same groupby:

```
print(df.groupby('Desc').sum())

# Only 'Duration (%)' column was included:
#       Duration (%)
# Desc              
# abc           87.5
# abcd          12.5
```

What I expected (a dataframe with 2 columns):

```
#   Desc Duration  Duration (%)
#    abc 03:30:00          87.5
#   abcd 00:30:00          12.5
```

Additional test: replace time_delta's with numeric values

```
df['Duration'] = [1.5, 2, 0.5]
print(df.groupby('Desc').sum())

#       Duration  Duration (%)
# Desc                        
# abc        3.5          87.5
# abcd       0.5          12.5
```

(Now it shows both columns as expected).

Is there a reason why columns with a `dtype` of `timedelta64[ns]` will only be included in the groupby when there are no other columns of numeric types?

Comment: Just a guess, I think in the groupby aggregation, `numeric_only=True` is set.(Might have to check the source code to be sure about that). Try this, and you'll see that your results come out, with the duration column included : ``df.groupby("Desc").sum(numeric_only=False)``

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy that solves the problem!  Although it's a little odd that `df.groupby("Desc").sum(numeric_only=False)` includes the timedeltas when there are no numeric columns present...

Comment: Yea, the source code will definitely have more details about the implementation

Comment: Sorry, in previous comment I meant to say: `df.groupby("Desc").sum(numeric_only=True)` includes the timedeltas when there are no numeric columns present.

Comment: interesting. I guess digging into the source code could help, explain this.

Comment: I had a quick look in `class NDFrame` and found `if numeric_only: data = self._get_numeric_data()` which calls `self._constructor(self._mgr.get_numeric_data()).__finalize__(self)` and at that point I got lost...

Comment: hahaha, yea, pandas source code can be opaque the first time. But if you spend time with it, you will get the hang of it. You probably have to look for the module that has get_numeric_data, to see what it does. It is a good way to learn and improve coding though

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead:

```
sum_df = df.groupby(['Desc']).agg({'Duration': 'sum', 'Duration (%)': 'sum'})
```

and get

```
     Duration  Duration (%)
Desc                       
abc  03:30:00          87.5
abcd 00:30:00          12.5
```

Comment: Thanks.  @sammywemmy has found a solution in the comments to the question.